# FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. org/apache/hadoop/metrics/Updater (state=08S01,code=-101)

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, beeline

Running complex queries (like join, group by) using beeline hiveserver2 cli produces this error:

CLI Output:

```
> select id, count(\*) from test group by id;

INFO  : Compiling command(queryId=root_20231116121644_eeaf897a-38b5-4276-9a92-234a8336233d): select id, count(*) from test group by id
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO  : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:\[FieldSchema(name:id, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:\_c1, type:bigint, comment:null)\], properties:null)
INFO  : Completed compiling command(queryId=root_20231116121644_eeaf897a-38b5-4276-9a92-234a8336233d); Time taken: 0.251 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
INFO  : Executing command(queryId=root_20231116121644_eeaf897a-38b5-4276-9a92-234a8336233d): select id, count(*) from test group by id
WARN  : Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
INFO  : Query ID = root_20231116121644_eeaf897a-38b5-4276-9a92-234a8336233d
INFO  : Total jobs = 1
INFO  : Launching Job 1 out of 1
INFO  : Starting task \[Stage-1:MAPRED\] in serial mode
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
INFO  : In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=\<number\>
INFO  : In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.max=\<number\>
INFO  : In order to set a constant number of reducers:
INFO  :   set mapreduce.job.reduces=\<number\>
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. org/apache/hadoop/metrics/Updater
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=root_20231116121644_eeaf897a-38b5-4276-9a92-234a8336233d); Time taken: 0.041 seconds
INFO  : Concurrency mode is disabled, not creating a lock manager
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. org/apache/hadoop/metrics/Updater (state=08S01,code=-101)
```

The same query runs fine on hive cli without any issues.

Have read similar threads and tried increasing mapred memory and disabling hive.auto.convert.join but to no avail.

Comment: Issue was with hive.exec.scratchdir. It should be on HDFS and not local FS 
For MR (use /tmp/hive instead of file:///tmp/hive)